# Get Users Last known location using location dialog

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch users last known location after user clicks OK on enable location dialog.Someone please let me know where should i need to implement get last known location functionality.

Below is my code:

```
public class BrodReceiver extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
     GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener{

LinearLayout linear;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED";
private static final int ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID = 3;
private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_brod_receiver);

    linear = findViewById(R.id.linear);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    checkPermissions();
  }

 @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
  }

 @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

private void checkPermissions(){

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(BrodReceiver.this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            requestLocationPermission();
        else
            showSettingDialog();
    } else
        showSettingDialog();
}

 private void requestLocationPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(BrodReceiver.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BrodReceiver.this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID);

    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BrodReceiver.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID);
     }
   }

  private void showSettingDialog(){

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);//5 sec Time interval for location update
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {

            final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = locationSettingsResult.getLocationSettingsStates();

            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {

                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS activated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(BrodReceiver.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                    break;
            }
        }
    });
  }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

      switch(requestCode){

          case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:

              switch(resultCode){

                  case RESULT_OK:
                      Log.e("Settings", "Result OK");

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      //startLocationUpdates();
                      break;
                  case RESULT_CANCELED:
                      Log.e("Settings", "Result Cancel");
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      break;
              }

              break;
      }

   }

}
```

After launching app it shows something like this

[image]

After clicking OK I want to fetch user last known location.Someone please let me know how to achieve the same.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage("to continue, turn on device location, which uses Google's location service")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 6000, 10, this);
                    Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    return l;
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("NO THANKS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .create()
            .show();
```

for API levels > 23, you must ask for runtime permissions before you can get the users last known location